# force a <br /> at end of div

Tags: css

I'm wondering is there a way of doing the following using CSS alone. When `</div>` is called on a specific div that a `<br />` would be added.

Comment: You can't add tags using CSS. What are you *actually* trying to do? Just add some space to the bottom of a div?

Comment: I've got a div that's creating content dynamically... things are getting mashed together, I'd like a line of whitespace between them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to create a gap below your `<div>`, in most cases giving it a bottom margin will do the trick:

```
#some-div {
    margin-bottom: 1em; /* Adjust depending on your text's line-height */
}
```

Comment: Good solution. In theory, 1em should be equal to <br />. Also, sometimes browsers can 'miss' <br /> tag.

Answer (score -1):

```
div:after {
    content: '<br />';
}
```

Doesn't do what you want it to do, but it does literally.